# Promise not resolving from recursive function with setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, async-await, generator

I want to execute some code after a certain delay in a loop. And once all the iterations are done, I want to do some other tasks. These depend on the results obtained from task1. For this I have written the following code snippet using generator, async/await and promise:

```
function* iter() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) yield i
}

async function start() {
    var myIter = iter();
    var p = await cb1(myIter);
    console.log('after await');
        p.then((value) => {
        console.log('-----------here-------------');
    });
}

start();

function cb1(myIter) {
    console.log("Started : " + new Date());
    var obj;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
        if(myIter.next().done === true) {
            console.log("End : " + new Date());
            resolve('done');
        }else {
            console.log("---in else---");
            cb1(myIter);
        }
    }, 3000);
    });
}
```

The issue is, the console in p.then() never gets printed. This means that the promise never gets resolved and the program terminates. The iterations execute as expected, but the promise never resolves. What could be wrong here? I am using recursion to trigger iterator.next() and want to resolve the promise only on the last iteration, that is when done=true.

Scratching my head since long on this issue. Help is appreciated. Following is the output of this program.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple problems: the line

```
var p = await cb1(myIter);
```

results in `p` being assigned the *value* of the result of calling `cb1`. `p` is *not* a `Promise` unless the constructed `Promise` *resolves* to a `Promise` as well, which is unusual. Because `await` essentially pauses the execution of the script until the promise resolves, you don't need `.then` - you just need to add the `console.log` below in the `start` function. Once you chain the promises together properly, `p` will resolve to a *string* of `'done'`, which of course isn't a `Promise`.

But there's another problem: your promises returned by `cb1` never resolve, except at the very end, where yuo're calling `resolve`. In the `else`, you're not ever calling `resolve`, so those promises remains unresolved forever. To fix this, change

```
  } else {
    console.log("---in else---");
    cb1(myIter);
  }
```

to

```
  } else {
    console.log("---in else---");
    cb1(myIter).then(resolve);
  }
```

so that the current iteration's `Promise` resolves once the *next* iteration's `Promise` resolves.

```js
function* iter() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) yield i
}

async function start() {
  var myIter = iter();
  var p = await cb1(myIter);
  console.log('after await');
  console.log('-----------here-------------');
}

start();

function cb1(myIter) {
  console.log("Started : " + new Date());
  var obj;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (myIter.next().done === true) {
        console.log("End : " + new Date());
        resolve('done');
      } else {
        console.log("---in else---");
        cb1(myIter).then(resolve);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you so much. This is interesting and I learnt something I did not know.

Comment: Good answer as always, but: *"`p` is not a `Promise` unless the constructed `Promise` resolves to a `Promise` as well, which is unusual."* is incorrect. `p` will never be a promise. If you pass promise B into the `resolve` of promise A, promise A isn't resolved, it's slaved to promise B -- it will resolve or reject based on what promise B does: http://jsfiddle.net/duj134qv/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Somebody, preferably you or the person who suggested this answer should warn the OP, that you are creating n Promises with n being the iteration number and are resolving backwards. Set i to 5000 or so and watch the ram bloat. This is not a production viable code, I am sure you are aware of that.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin - Well, it's CertainPerformance's answer. I don't do that in mine, I see no point to the additional promises.

Comment: Is this inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

Need 1 more function then it works:

```
   function* iter() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) yield i
}

async function start() {
    var myIter = iter();
    var p = await cb1(myIter);
    console.log('after await');
    console.log("here is p:" + p.done + "," + p.value);
}

start();

function repeat(myIter,resolver,previous){
    var temp;
    if((temp = myIter.next()).done === true) {
        console.log("End : " + new Date());
        resolver(previous);
    }else {
        console.log("---in else---");
        setTimeout(function(){repeat(myIter,resolver,temp)},3000);
    }
}

function cb1(myIter) {
    console.log("Started : " + new Date());
    var obj;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       repeat(myIter,resolve);
    });
}
```

Also fixed the p, await gets it out, and you needed to grab the previous value

Comment: ok fixed it, he should not wait till done though, needs to grab the previous

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

1. The result of `await` will never be a promise; the purpose of `await` is to wait for the promise to resolve and give you the *resolution value*. So `p` in your code isn't a promise, and won't have a `then` method. But you're not getting an error about that because of #2.
2. **Each** call to `cb1` creates a new promise, with a new `resolve` function. Your last `setTimeout` callback is resolving the last promise, but nothing ever resolves the first one, so you never get past that `var p = await cb1(myIter);` line.

You probably want an inner function for the timer callback, and then have the promise returned by the `cb1` call resolve.

Something along these lines:

```
function* iter() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}

async function start() {
    var myIter = iter();
    var p = await cb1(myIter);
    console.log("p = ", p);
}

start();
function cb1(myIter) {
    console.log("Started : " + new Date());
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        iteration();
        function iteration() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (myIter.next().done) { // `=== done` is pointless here
                    console.log("End : " + new Date());
                    resolve('done');
                } else {
                    console.log("---in else---");
                    iteration();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response